# Keep the header and footer fixed while loading a different page?

Tags: intel-xdk

[image: Picture Demo]

I have a button and footer

I want to click the button for redirect to a website but keep the footer fixed.

Please help me. I use Intel XDK

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When adding new page, add it as a subpage, this should keep the header and footer same:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can try loading that website on the same page keeping the header and footer unchanged, this is what I prefer when I want to do the same. Or if you want to load in a different page, then create a sub page and load the website on that page.